# ¿Como refactorizar este analizador de datos IRC?

Tags: c#, revisión-de-código

Tengo este metodo *monstro* que tiene 1500 lineas de código lleno de condiciones y casos.

[Método](https://github.com/icechat/IceChat/blob/5465bf52766c3aba1b34a03f0e4a734d67495a45/IRCConnection/ParseIRCData.cs#L137-L1765) (No copió el método aquí por que demandará toda la pantalla y sería molesto hacer scroll - El link esta fijado a un commit para que futuras actualizaciones no lo rompan)

Por lo que vi en estas situación, lo ideal es aplicar el patrón de factoría. Pero, ¿se podría simplificar aún más?

Answer (score 3):

Lo que noto es que hay un case enorme que podría ser eliminado si implementas algo como:

```
public class ParseData{
    public string nick {get;set;}
    public string msg {get;set;}

} 
interface IIRCParse{
    ParseData Parse();
}

public IRCParse001 : IIRCParse{

    public ParseData Parse()
    {
        //implementacion
    }
}

public IRCParse006 : IIRCParse{

    public ParseData Parse()
    {
        //implementacion
    }
}

//resto implementaciones
```

Cada código se parsea de forma separada en una clase, y todas heredan de una interfaz.
Y lo usarías por medio de:

```
Dictionary<string, IIRCParse> ircParses = new Dictionary<string, IIRCParse>(){
    {"001", new IRCParse001()},
    {"006", new IRCParse006()},
    //resto
};

IIRCParse parseInstance = ircParses[ircData[1]]
ParseData data = parseInstance.Parse();
```

de esta forma evitas el `switch` enorme y puedes separar cada codigo en una implementación distinta
El desafió es normalizar el parse para todos los códigos, que devuelvan un mismo set de datos como respuesta

En el ejemplo usa un `Dictionary` pero su usas alguna librería de IoC (Unity, Ninject, StruncturaMap, autofac, etc) aun mejor, ya que en esta podrías mapear el código a una implementacion y aplicar el resolve para determinar que instancia de parser aplica.